# How to show Native App Install Prompt on Chrome on mobile?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I develop native app for websites.
and would like to prompt app installation on the website, like below.
[Screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEDgp.jpg)

( I see a similar popup on Facebook for mobile websites.

I assume it's not PWA, and it can show a link to the app or Play Store for installing the native app.

So, what is this exactly?
and how to show it on the website?

I found this page.
but not sure it's about the UI which I wanted to implement.
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/app-install-banners-native/